# Parse rate limit - what counts towards this limit?

Tags: parse-platform

Recently, I have been hitting Parse rate limit every time my servers try to upload data to Parse. What is not clear to me is why.

I use batch inserts, batch updates and batch deletes. I even throttle the batch operations themselves (0.25 seconds between operations) yet I still get this in my logs:

```
10/03/2015 04:05:17 AM loading to Parse
10/03/2015 04:05:50 AM Inserted: 851
10/03/2015 04:05:50 AM Updated: {u'code': 155, u'error': u'This application performed 1802 requests within the past minute, and exceeded its request limit. Please retry in one  minute or raise your request limit.'}
```

What I am not clear about is whether a batch still counts as individual operation or does Parse look at it as 50 inserts (for example). If it does then what's the point? If it does not treat a batch as individual operations then how can 1802 requests broken down to batches of 50 in 0.25 secs bursts hit this limit?

And before you ask, no app tester is even trying to pull the data as they were all asleep!!!

I followed/read various links including [this](https://parse.com/plans/faq) one and [this](https://www.parse.com/questions/30-requests-per-second-equates-to-how-many-concurrent-users) one but am still puzzled.

Any advice will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to [Parse's plan FAQ](https://parse.com/plans/faq):

> Batched requests will be counted based on the number of operations
>   performed in each batch.

The way I read it is: 1802 requests in batches of 50 will still count as 1802 operations.

There are also paragraphs in there regarding "How are requests/second calculated" and what causes a 155 error code to be generated.

Answer (score 0):

Well, found the answer [here](https://parse.com/docs/rest/guide#objects-batch-operations) in batch operations section, just before data types:

> Note that N requests sent in a batch will still count toward your
>   request limit as N requests.